# PyQt5 WindowsVista style instead of Win10 style

Tags: python, pyqt5, manifest

When I design a UI with PyQt5, in Qt Designer it looks like win10 app. But when I start a program in VS Code or just run a file, it looks like in Windows Vista or 7. How to fix that? I haven't changed style in the code

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'untitled.ui'), self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = UI()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[how it looks in designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3To5i.png)

[how it really looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leVlj.png)

Comment: is that your windows default settings ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the display style by using [app.setStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setStyle). To get a list of available styles on your system try this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyleFactory
print(QStyleFactory.keys())
```

on my system I get:

```
['Breeze', 'Oxygen', 'Windows', 'Fusion']
```

Probably you'll get difference choices on a Windows box.

To evaluate different styles try:

```
app.setStyle('<style name here>')
```

or

```
 app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('style name here'))
```

Comment: `app.setStyle(string)` actually *does* call `setStyle(QStyleFactory.create(string))`, so the second solution, while correct, is actually redundant (except for the rare case for which any of those function is overridden).